# Get changes from specific commit without changes from parent

Tags: git

Say I have a text file with the contents

```
A
```

I commit the file (commit febcdb0).  Then I make another change and now the file contains:

```
A
B
```

And it is committed (commit 0d03344).  Then I make another change:

```
A
B
C
```

And it is also committed (4077fb8).  Is there a way to remove the second commit, so I end up with:

```
A
C
```

without ending up with a conflict like this:

```
A
<<<<<<< HEAD
B
C
======
>>>>>>> parent of 0d03344... B
```

That is - I specifically want the changes introduced with the last commit, but I want to discard changes from the previous commit?

I've tried interactive rebase and cherry-picking, but nothing seems to work.

So if I do:

```
git checkout fedcbd0
git checkout -b test
git cherry-pick 4077fb8
```

I get as a response:

```
Automatic cherry-pick failed.  After resolving the conflicts,
mark the corrected paths with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
and commit the result with:

    git commit -c 4077fb8
```

With the contents of the file being the conflict above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a good way to do this without causing a merge conflict. In commit 4077fb8, the line `C` is added after the line `B` and before the end of the file. If you try to directly apply that change to febcdb0, Git will not be able to accurately insert the new line `C` between `B` and end-of-file, because there is no line `B`. Because this change is not far enough away from the previous commit 0d03344, Git errs on the side of caution here and generates a merge conflict that you must resolve.

Comment: Is there maybe a `--strategy` flag I could set or something which would tell git to behave a little less cautiously?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Taken by itself, the patch to insert `C` requires at least the existence of `B` to proceed. The consideration of "context" lines around applied patches is fundamental to the concept of applying patch differences.

Answer (score 2):

with `git cherry-pick` you can apply the changes introduced by some existing commits. In your case you can go back to the first commit and create a new branch, then use cherry-pick to apply there the last commit so that at the end you will remove the second commit

```
git checkout -b new_branch febcdb0

git cherry-pick 4077fb8
```